# Batch Script - Empty Multiple Directories In Paths With A Pattern

Tags: batch-file, path

I'm looking to write a short batch script that will delete all files within a set of directories. More specifically, suppose I have the top directory "workspace" and it contains several directories beginning with the sting "project" (e.g. project-something, project-another). Then each of these "project" directories contain a "model" directory. I want to have the script empty each of these model directories.

I know this is doesn't work, but I looking for something along the lines of

```
del project*\model\*
```

But I know that the * after project will not select all directories starting with project then proceed into the model directories to clear them. What would be a correct way to go about doing this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into a .bat file and run.

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in (`dir /ad /s /b model`) do (
    del /s /q "%%F"
    echo Removed "%%F"
)

pause
```

Comment: This does exactly what I asked for. Thanks!